# Populating HTML Select dropdown from a database in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor, return

I've not been able to find the correct answer on this so seeing if the stackOverflow crew can help.  I know it seems like a common thing, but this example is a little different from what I've found whilst searching.

I have a meteor template that has a select dropdown in it with the relevant part as such:

```
    {{#each phoneNumber}} 
        <li>
            <input id="{{this._id}}" type="text" name="phoneNumberItem" placeholder="Phone number here"  value="{{number}}">
            <select id="{{this._id}}" name="type">
            <!-- go through collection and see which is selected there, mark it as selected here so they match -->
                <option selected="{{selectedOrNot}}" name="selection">Work</option>
                <option selected="{{selectedOrNot}}" name="selection">Home</option>
                <option selected="{{selectedOrNot}}" name="selection">Mobile</option>
                <option selected="{{selectedOrNot}}" name="selection">Office</option>
                <option selected="{{selectedOrNot}}" name="selection">Fax</option>
                <option selected="{{selectedOrNot}}" name="selection">Other</option>
            </select>
            <input id="{{this._id}}" type="button" class="remove" value="X">
        </li>
    {{/each}}
```

The complete code for the helper that selectedOrNot is in is shown as such:

```
  Template.addPhoneNumber.helpers({

    //the full list of phone numbers in the collection, so we can loop through them in the template and draw them into the form
    'phoneNumber': function() {
      return newOrgPhoneNumbers.find();
    },


    //let's us choose which of the dropdown items are selected
    'selectedOrNot': function(event){

      var collectionType = newOrgPhoneNumbers.findOne();  //get the type from the collection (EG: Home, Mobile, Fax, etc)
      var typeFormName = $('[name="selection"]').val();   //get the data from the form (EG: Home, Mobile, Fax, etc)


      //When drawing the select dropdown, see if there's a match and return selected if so
     if(collectionType.type === typeFormName){
      console.log ('selected!');
      return 'selected';
     }

  }

  });
```

What I'm trying to do:

I have data stored in a collection called newOrgPhoneNumbers.

This data includes a "type" that has either "Home", "Mobile", "Work", etc in it.

When I draw the select dropdown in the template, I want the selected to be chosen for the option that matches the "type" in the newOrgPhoneNumbers collection.  Note that there are multiple select dropdowns, one for each item in the data collection.  So there may be say, 6 phone numbers in the form, each with its own ID taken from the collection it's drawn from.

For the purposes of this example, the collection data has "Home" as the "type", so I want it to draw with Home being selected in the select dropdown.

Now I can see what's wrong here.  The typeFormName is taking the VALUE of the selector dropdown, which is always "Work" by default.

How can I rework this to make a match in my If condition and return a "selected" when I get a match?  I think I need to retrieve a value from the template that matches the value in the collection but the selector dropdown doesn't have such a value (as it's always "work" when drawn).

I've spent about 5 hours today on this with various logic attempts so it's time to ask.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to @Sasikanth. This is what he's helped me with and it's provided in full below to help others / future reference.

Meteor Template:

```
{{#each phoneNumber}} 
        <li>
            <input id="{{this._id}}" type="text" name="phoneNumberItem" placeholder="Phone number here"  value="{{number}}">
            <select id="sel_{{this._id}}" name="type">
            <!-- go through collection and see which is selected there, mark it as selected here so they match -->
                <option value="Work">Work</option>
                <option value="Home">Home</option>
                <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                <option value="Office">Office</option>
                <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            {{setDropdownValue}}
            <input id="{{this._id}}" type="button" class="remove" value="X">
        </li>
    {{/each}}
```

Meteor Helper:

```
  Template.addPhoneNumber.helpers({

    //the full list of phone numbers in the collection, so we can loop through them in the template and draw them into the form
    'phoneNumber': function() {
      return newOrgPhoneNumbers.find();
    },

    //This will take the value of the database item's "type" field and send it back to the select html element.  
    //It's using the sel_ prefix to separate it from the other items with the same id in the template so they don't receive the data by accident.
    'setDropdownValue': function(){
     $("#sel_"+this._id).val(this.type);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
//let's us choose which of the dropdown items are selected
    'selectedOrNot': function(event){

      var collectionType = newOrgPhoneNumbers.findOne();  //get the type from the collection (EG: Home, Mobile, Fax, etc)
      var typeFormName = $('[name="selection"]').val();   //get the data from the form (EG: Home, Mobile, Fax, etc)


      //When drawing the select dropdown, see if there's a match and return selected if so
     if(collectionType.type === typeFormName){
      console.log ('selected!');
      return 'selected';
     }

  }
```

try this

```
//let's us choose which of the dropdown items are selected
    'selectedOrNot': function(event){
      var typeFormName = $('[name="selection"]').val();   //get the data from the form (EG: Home, Mobile, Fax, etc)


      //When drawing the select dropdown, see if there's a match and return selected if so
     if(this.type === typeFormName){
      console.log ('selected!');
      return 'selected';
     }
  }
```

make sure you're getting correct values for both by `console.log`

**EDIT**

try following code

```
{{#each phoneNumber}} 
        <li>
            <input id="{{this._id}}" type="text" name="phoneNumberItem" placeholder="Phone number here"  value="{{number}}">
            <select id="{{this._id}}" name="type">
            <!-- go through collection and see which is selected there, mark it as selected here so they match -->
                <option value="Work">Work</option>
                <option value="Home">Home</option>
                <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                <option value="Office">Office</option>
                <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            {{setDropdownValue}}
            <input id="{{this._id}}" type="button" class="remove" value="X">
        </li>
    {{/each}}
```

in the helpers

```
setDropdownValue: function(){
 $("#"+this._id).val(this.type);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is more efficient yes, much appreciated.  Unfortunately though, the result is still the same.  this.type does return what the database holds (great).  typeFormName returns "Work" each time.  The selector has all the other options in the dropdown (mobile, work, home, etc) but "Work" is selected by default and as I say, typeFormName returns "Work".  This seems to be the problem and I can't find a way to beat it yet.

Comment: @robster, why do you need `typeFormName` here? from your question I understand this, you have phone number records each with `type` property and you want to select that `type` from dropdown by default,am I correct? If I'm correct I have different solution for that

Comment: You're stretching my beginners brain and I appreciate it. :-)  I gave that a go but don't fully understand the line $("#"+this._id).val(this.type);  I believe it's taking the value of the form element and doing something with it?  I'm also not sure how it works with the {{setDropdownValue}} in the template?  I'm sorry I'm not so advanced yet.   Currently it doesn't update the form and as I'm not skilled enough yet I'm not sure why.  As it stands, the form draws as it always has with your adjusted code.  Thanks again...

Comment: OK a bit more testing and it turns out that the input has the same ID as does the button.  So if I try and type into the input, it rewrites itself as HOME.  So I see we're setting the form object with the ID as HOME but in this case they all have the same ID.  They share the database ID (used in other processing).  In this case I'll need to have a different identifer for the select dropdown.  I'll have a play with what you've given me so far and see what I can come up with.  Getting there slowly.  Thanks again

Comment: yeah I didn't observe that, for select you can give like `<select id="sel_{{this._id}}" name="type">` and in the helper you can use `$("#sel_"+this._id).val(this.type);` here just for diffrentiating of id's I prepended id with `sel_` hope that helps